# JavaScript Print function issue

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When I clicked Ön Izleme (Span/Button) , i come the back i cant use my JavaScript Function Like Draggable Resize method on my divs. Do anyone can help me ? Önizleme Button job is print 
When i back to from print screen i cant use my JavaScript function Like Draggable and resize. What is the my fault do anyone can help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.divKolon {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:3px solid #DD4B39; background-color: #E98A7E;float:left;}
.divKolon-resizable-e{
    height: 50px !important;
}
.divUstKolon {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:3px solid #DD4B39;  text-align:center;float:left;margin-right:20px;}

.shadow(@shadow){
  -webkit-box-shadow:@shadow;
  -mox-box-shadow:@shadow;
  box-shadow:@shadow;
}


.label-danger{

    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;

}

</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

var Bosluk=0;
var SecilenItem;
var VTBilgileri=[];
var YaziFont;
var YaziBoyutu;

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    //console.log(ev.target);
}

function drop(ev) {

    ev.stopPropagation()
    var EklenecekDiv=ev.target;
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    //console.log(ev.target);
    console.log($(ev.target).parent());


    var divim=ev.target;

        var c = divim.children;
        console.log(c.lenght);
            /*if(c[2]==null)
            {
                 EklenecekDiv=$($(ev.target).parent());
                 EklenecekDiv.append()
                var label1=document.getElementById(data);

                var MyLabelAdd1=document.createElement("div");
                MyLabelAdd1.appendChild(document.createTextNode($(label1).html()));
                $(MyLabelAdd1).attr("name","KolonAdi");
                EklenecekDiv.append(MyLabelAdd1);
                divim.remove();
                label1.remove();
                return;
                console.log(EklenecekDiv);
            }




        if(c[3]!=null)
        {
            c[3].remove();

        }*/




    var label=document.getElementById(data);

    var MyLabelAdd=document.createElement("div");

    MyLabelAdd.appendChild(document.createTextNode($(label).html()));
        $(MyLabelAdd).attr("name","KolonAdi");
        if(YaziFont!=null&&YaziBoyutu!=null){MyLabelAdd.style.fontFamily=YaziFont; }
        if(YaziBoyutu!=null){alert(YaziBoyutu); MyLabelAdd.style.fontSize =YaziBoyutu+"px"; }

    EklenecekDiv.appendChild(MyLabelAdd);
    label.remove();
}
function tiklandi()
{

    alert("Okey");
}
function Click(e){
    if(SecilenItem==null)
    {
        alert("Lütfen Alan Seçiniz");
        return;
    }

    var item=SecilenItem;
    var div=document.getElementById("Itemler");
    var label=document.createElement("span");
    $(label).addClass("label label-danger col-xs-1");
    $(label).attr("id","drag");
    $(label).attr("draggable","true");
    $(label).attr("ondragstart","drag(event)");

    $(label).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      $(this).remove();
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 


    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    div.appendChild(label);
    //console.log($(label).html());


    var KolonDiv=document.createElement("div");
    $(KolonDiv).attr("ondrop","drop(event)")
    $(KolonDiv).attr("ondragover","allowDrop(event)");
    $(KolonDiv).addClass("divKolon");
    KolonDiv.style.marginLeft=Bosluk+"px";
    $(KolonDiv).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      $(this).remove();
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 

    $(KolonDiv).resizable();
    $(KolonDiv).draggable();

    var Kolonlar=document.getElementById("Kolonlar");
    Kolonlar.appendChild(KolonDiv);





};

function CiktiGetir(e){
    var KolonlarinChildren=document.getElementsByClassName("divKolon");
    var printContents = document.getElementById("Kolonlar");
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    printContents=printContents.innerHTML;



     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;


}
function TabloAlanTiklandi (e){



     SecilenItem=$(e).text();
     $(e).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html( $(e).text()  );
    //e.remove();
}

function FontLi(e)
{
    YaziFont=$(e).text();
     $(e).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html( $(e).text()  );
}

function StilDegistir(e)
{

}

function EkAlanClick(e){
    if($("#EkAlan").val()==null)
    {
        alert("Lütfen Alan Giriniz");
        return;
    }
    var h1=document.createElement("h1");
    var item=$("#EkAlan").val();
    var div=document.getElementById("Itemler");
    var label=document.createElement("span");
    $(label).addClass("label label-danger col-xs-1");
    $(label).attr("id","drag");
    $(label).attr("draggable","true");
    $(label).attr("ondragstart","drag(event)");

    $(label).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      $(this).remove();
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 


    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    div.appendChild(label);
    //console.log($(label).html());


    var KolonDiv=document.createElement("div");
    $(KolonDiv).attr("ondrop","drop(event)")
    $(KolonDiv).attr("ondragover","allowDrop(event)");
    $(KolonDiv).addClass("divKolon");
    $(KolonDiv).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      $(this).remove();
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 

    $(KolonDiv).resizable();
    $(KolonDiv).draggable();

    var Kolonlar=document.getElementById("Kolonlar");
    Kolonlar.appendChild(KolonDiv);


$("#EkAlan").val("");



}

function BoslukEkle(e)
{
    if($("#Aralik").val().lenght==0)
    {
        alert("Aralik Degeri Giriniz");
        return;
    }
    Bosluk=$("#Aralik").val();
    alert(Bosluk);
    $("#Aralik").val("");
}

function BoyutEkle(e)
{
    if($("#YaziBoyutu").val().lenght==0)
    {
        alert("Boyut Degeri Giriniz");
        return;
    }
YaziBoyutu=$("#YaziBoyutu").val();
$("#YaziBoyutu").val("");   

}


</script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Calendar</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->

  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">



  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->


  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->


    <!-- Main content -->
   <div class="divUstKolon col-xs-12" id="Itemler" style="height:50px"></div>
   <div class=" col-xs-12" style="margin-top:20px" >
<div class="dropdown col-xs-1" style="height:32px " >
    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Alan Ekle
    <span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul id="Secenekler" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a onClick="TabloAlanTiklandi(this)" href="#">Isim</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="TabloAlanTiklandi(this)"href="#">SoyIsim</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="TabloAlanTiklandi(this)" href="#">Adress</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="TabloAlanTiklandi(this)" href="#">Numara</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="TabloAlanTiklandi(this)" href="#">Yaş</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="TabloAlanTiklandi(this)" href="#">Tanıdık 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<label class="btn btn-default col-xs-1" style="margin-left :10px ; height:32px " id="Ekle" onClick="Click(this)"> Ekle </label>

    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <input style="margin-left :10px ; height:32px " type="text" class="col-xs-1" id="EkAlan">

      <label style="margin-left :10px ; height:32px" class="btn btn-default col-xs-1" id="Ekle" onClick="EkAlanClick(this)"> Ek Alan Ekle </label>

      <div class="col-xs-4" ></div>
    <label class="btn btn-danger col-xs-1" id="CiktiGetir" style="margin-right :10px" onClick="CiktiGetir(this)" >Ön İzleme</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary col-xs-1" id="CiktiGetir" style="margin-right :10px" onClick="CiktiGetir(this)" >Ana Sayfa</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:10px">

<input style="margin-left :10px ; height:32px " type="text" class="col-xs-1" id="YaziBoyutu" placeholder="Yazı Boyutu">

<label style="margin-left :10px ; height:32px" class="btn btn-default col-xs-1"  onClick="BoyutEkle(this)"> Değiştir</label>
<div class="col-xs-1" ></div>
<div class="dropdown col-xs-2" style="height:32px " >
    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Yazı Font
    <span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul id="Fontlar" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Georgia</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)"href="#">Palatino Linotype</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Book Antiqua</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Times New Roman</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Arial</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Helvetica</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Arial Black</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Impact</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Lucida Sans Unicode</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Tahoma</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Verdana</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Courier New</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="FontLi(this)" href="#">Lucida Console</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<label style="margin-left :10px ; height:32px" class="btn btn-default col-xs-1" id="Ekle" onClick="StilDegistir(this)"> Yazi Stil Değiştir</label>
<div class="col-xs-1" ></div>

</div>


<div class="col-xs-12" id="Kolonlar" style="margin-top :10px"> </div>






    <!-- /.content -->

  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->



  <!-- Control Sidebar -->

  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>

<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<!-- fullCalendar 2.2.5 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page specific script -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an optimal solution but can you try replacing `CiktiGetir` function with this:

```
function CiktiGetir(e){
    var htmlElement = document.querySelector("html");
    var printContents = document.getElementById("Kolonlar");

    // Make body invisible, append new element to HTML
    document.body.style.display = "none";
    htmlElement.appendChild(printContents);

    window.print();

    // Make body visible again, remove the added element
    document.body.style.display = "initial";
    htmlElement.removeChild(printContents);
}
```

Replacing HTML content breaks the JS events and dynamic contents.

Comment: I get very very more space in the paper. It's bad idea :(

Comment: I get White screen now :/ just white . nothing added my page when i back on the print screen

Comment: Then, try replacing  `htmlElement.appendChild(printContents);` with `htmlElement.insertBefore(printContents, document.body);`. It should've worked btw, I don't know why it didn't. Also if it doesn't work too, please try it with `document.body.style.visibility = "hidden"` instead of `display = "none"`

Comment: Again i get some issiue .. What are our fault ?

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the body HTML

```
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

So you will need to reatach the events.

Try the "on" jquery method. Something like

```
$(document).on('click', '#CiktiGetir', function() { CiktiGetir(); });
```

Comment: it doesnt work same issue again when i back the Page i cant use my javascript function..

Comment: My code was just an example. You will have to adapt it to your code.

You need to reatach the events after replace body content.

You dont want to to this, you can refresh the entire page.

function CiktiGetir(e){
    var KolonlarinChildren=document.getElementsByClassName("divKolon");
     var printContents = document.getElementById("Kolonlar");
     printContents=printContents.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     location.reload();
}

Answer (score 0):

My code was just an example. You will have to adapt it to your code.

You need to reatach the events after replace body content.

If, you dont want to to this, you can refresh the entire page.

```
function CiktiGetir(e){
    var KolonlarinChildren=document.getElementsByClassName("divKolon");
     var printContents = document.getElementById("Kolonlar");
     printContents=printContents.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I dont need this . I lose my divs if i reloaded.